How to compute derivatives on multiple output in parallel
I'm working on a Physics Informed Neural Network that has two inputs and N outputs. The loss function contains high-order derivatives of the outputs with respect to the inputs x and y.
Is it possible to compute the derivatives in parallel without a for loop?
def gradient(y, x, grad_outputs=None):
    if grad_outputs is None:
        grad_outputs = torch.ones_like(y)
    grad = torch.autograd.grad(y, [x], grad_outputs=grad_outputs, create_graph=True)[0]
    return grad


def compute_derivatives(x, y, u):
    dudx = gradient(u, x)
    dudy = gradient(u, y)

    dudxx = gradient(dudx, x)
    dudyy = gradient(dudy, y)

    dudxxx = gradient(dudxx, x)
    dudxxy = gradient(dudxx, y)
    dudyyy = gradient(dudy, y)

    dudxxxx = gradient(dudxxx, x)
    dudxxyy = gradient(dudxxy, y)
    dudyyyy = gradient(dudyyy, y)

    return dudxx, dudyy, dudxxxx, dudyyyy, dudxxyy

The code above works fine for a single output. For N outputs the shape of u is [batch_size, N] and I need to compute the derivatives for each column of u in parallel so that each derivative (ex. dudx, dudy..) shape matches the shape of u.
Which is the most efficient way to do this?
Thanks in advance.
